# Помогите решить проблему с выходом за пределы массива

Tags: c++, массивы

В одномерном массиве, состоящем из `n` целых элементов, вычислить: количество пар `x[i]` и `x[i + 1]`, таких, что `x[i] < x[i + 1]`.

```
int otvet=0;  
for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    if(A[i]<A[i+1]){
        otvet=otvet+1;
    }
}
```

При просмотре элементов массива происходит выход за пределы массива. На массивах небольшой размерности могут быть ошибки только в вычислении количества пар, при больших размерностях программа может некорректно заканчивать свою работу. Подскажите, как это пофиксить?

Comment: Если массив `A` размером `n`, то на последней итерации цикла `A[i+1]` будет выходить за пределы массива

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Элементов в массиве `n`, но соседних пар только `n-1`.

Значит, вместо

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
```

примените

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){        // вместо n применено n-1
```

и таким образом вы сравните *все* соседние пары и `A[i+1]` *не выйдет за границы массива.*

(Между прочим, вместо `otvet=otvet+1;` красивее использовать *инкремент*: `otvet++;` или `++otvet;`)